# 2sxc module reinstallation

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke-7, 2sxc

The problem I’m experiencing is when uninstalling 2sxc in DNN 7.3.xx and then trying to reinstall it again I get an error (see below).  I believe that the DB has remnants of the installation and I tried going directly to the DB and removing constraints and foreign keys from all 2sxc module tables and entries from DNN tables. I also removed the stored procedures which belong to 2sxc module. This tells me that the uninstall didn’t really uninstall much and left data in the DB. This is dangerous but I tried anyway. Now I’m stuck and can’t install 2sxc again.  Could someone point me to the right place to:

- find the schema of 2sxc
- what DNN tables are affected when I install 2sxc module.

This is the error message below that I am getting when I try and install 2sxc module 7.3 (after having previously uninstalled v8.12 ):

> -- Author: Daniel Mettler -- Create date: 2013-01-28 -- Description: Automatically log all changes to the DataTimeline --
>   =============================================  EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AutoLogAllChangesToTimeline_Values] ON [dbo].[ToSIC_EAV_Values]
>   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE AS BEGIN –  SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent
>   extra result sets from -- interfering with SELECT statements. SET
>   NOCOUNT ON;

I couldn’t find the table [AutoLogAllChangesToTimeLine_Values] in the Database.

I'm just looking to get a solution to to remove all entries related with 2sxc module in the database.  It will enable me to reinstall 2sxc module in DNN 7.3.xx.

Comment: Some version numbers are confusing - could you clarify which dnn version, which 2sxc version-uninstall, which 2sxc version re-install? Just fyi: latest 2sxc (9.x) is only for DNN 7.4.2+

Comment: Hi Arun, DNN version is 07.03.04 and 2sxc was 8.12. 2sxc module installed successfully at the first time. When I was working on Template, it popped up an error message saying 'Had an error talking to the server (status 400). Message: Bad Request, Detail: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path2'. After that I reinstalled 2sxc module and I got the error related to database.

Comment: I'm going to make some guesses: The installation SQL does some things which vary from version to version. Some tables in the latest version are very different from the initial version, so running some scripts like "going from V5 to V6" when you already have V8 would fail. To me it feels like this may be what's happening. Did you correctly uninstall the module, or did you just delete the 2sxc files?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you want to simply "clean up to enable a fresh install" - here's probably what you need:

1. Uninstall the module
2. Make sure to manually delete the ToSexy-folder in Desktop modules. This may be the issue you have, because some versions of DNN are unreliable at giving 2sxc the correct versions, so 2sxc was forced to create helper files which cannot be auto-removed on un-install. Maybe these are causing version-detection problems, making 2sxc trying to upgrade when there is nothing there.
3. If you think the DB has some leftovers, just make sure you check for any tables and stored procedures beginning with ToSIC

Now you should really be good to go ;)

Comment: Hi iJungleBoy, many many thanks for your help. I finally reinstalled 2sxc module without having any error messages. Thanks again :)

Comment: Perfect :). Please mark the answer as correct, to help future searchers.